# How to change subtitle color in listVIew

Tags: android-listview

I have a `listView`. Each list item  consists of a title and a subtitle under title. I want to change the color of the subtitle. Please help me to change.

Answer (score 0):

This is the layout you can use to make a different color textview for your subtitle:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="#999999">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

**Color Change on this text view**

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</LinearLayout>
```

After this you can make your own adapter and inflate your row and you will get the different color on your txtview in the listview you mentioned.

Hope this helps.